# How to mount a digital camera for the right applications?

Tags: mount

Whenever I plug by digital camera in, a nice media-icon pops up. Great! !

When I right click on this icon, I can only open Rhythmbox or VLC-media-player. Both applications are rather senseless to be used here. When I want to download photos (be it
by means of F-Spot, Shotwell or Picasa) I have to unmount the camera first. This seems
to me rather illogical ? Why is the camera mounted if you have to unmount it to be used? How can I make that the digital camera is being mounted for the right applications?
It looks strange to me that one has to unmount a device before one can use it!

Camera model : **Canon PowerShot SX20** IS (new id has been added for this camera in libgphoto2 2.4.9. The packagemanager tells me that libgphoto2-2 is installed, version 2.4.8-0ubuntu2 => it looks like libgphoto2 can't read the camera? Anyway, the PTP/MTP-
mode works fine)

```
uname -a
Linux Ubuntu-Bernard **2.6.32-24-generic #42-Ubuntu** SMP Fri Aug 20 14:24:04 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="**Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS**"

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04a9:31e4 **Canon, Inc.** 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:1706 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. WL-167G 802.11g Adapter [ralink]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 050d:0234 Belkin Components F5U234 USB 2.0 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


Type filesystem = **gphoto2**

KernelLoggings (plug-in/plug-out)
Sep 11 19:23:55 Ubuntu-Bernard kernel: [ 1370.156803] usb 1-2.1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
Sep 11 19:23:55 Ubuntu-Bernard kernel: [ 1370.282419] usb 1-2.1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Sep 11 19:31:59 Ubuntu-Bernard kernel: [ 1854.101144] usb 1-2.1: USB disconnect, address 4


Detailled Camera info
lsusb -v

Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04a9:31e4 Canon, Inc. 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x04a9 Canon, Inc.
  idProduct          0x31e4 
  bcdDevice            0.02
  iManufacturer           1 Canon Inc.
  iProduct                2 Canon Digital Camera
  iSerial                 3 E2F5E9B80A584FFDA901B46ECBC87410
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           39
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0xc0
      Self Powered
    MaxPower                2mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           3
          bInterfaceClass         6 Imaging
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Still Image Capture
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Picture Transfer Protocol (PIMA 15470)
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x83  EP 3 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0008  1x 8 bytes
        bInterval              32
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0001
  Self Powered
```

Comment: Hi Bernard, we'll need a little more information. What model is the camera, what is the output of `lsusb` when it is plugged in, and what version of Ubuntu are you using? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can handle this through the Nautilus preferences.

1. Open Nautilus (**Places -> Home Folder**).
2. Click the **Edit** drop down menu.
3. Choose **Preferences**.
4. In the **File Management Preferences** window, click the **Media** tab.
5. The **Media Handling** section should allow you to configure the system to behave the way you want when you attach the camera.[1]

[1] The options next for **Photos**, include: *Ask what to do*, *Do Nothing*, *Open Folder*, *Open F-Spot*, *Open with other Application...*

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Jim. Changing the option next to Photos didn't help. However if I change the option musicplayer to be opened with eg. Shotwell Photomanager, then Shotwell is started! This means that a gphoto2-medium is considered as one of a musicplayer! However, the medium must be unmounted before Shotwell can use it. So changing these options does not solve the mount-problem.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in precise 12.04 - I don't see Media Handling in Nautilus prefs.  Nor do I find such settings in the System Settings window.  But typing "media" in the unity dash finds something just called "Details" with a "removable media" section that lets me do this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stab in the dark, but if you temporarily comment out the following lines in `/lib/udev/rules.d/45-libmtp8.rules`, does it help at all?

- ```
  # Canon PowerShot SX20IS (PTP/MTP mode)
  # ATTR{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="31e4", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio"
  ```
- ```
  # Canon PowerShot SX20IS (PTP/MTP mode)
  # ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="31e4", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio"
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot ændrük for your advice. I changed the rules, but i didn't help me any further. I googled around and found that this issue has (or is?) a bug. See http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1193340.html
http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=7205851&postcount=4.

Comment: sudo chmod -x /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor helps, but the camera-icon is no longer shown on the desktop. If the volume-monitor was allowed to run, you got gphoto2 --list-files
"Error initializing camera: -60: Could not lock the device". I think I better file a bug in launchad?

Comment: This problem was filed as a bug in 2008: 
camera automount prevents import : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/196757